# Google maps places embedding quick facts and tourist information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have a requirement to include Google maps places inside a website. They want it to look like:

[This kind of map](https://www.google.com/maps/place/London,+UK/@51.5287718,-0.2416805,11z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99!8m2!3d51.5073509!4d-0.1277583)

Is it possible to embed this using the Javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Google Maps supports iframes (iframes allows you to embed documents into your HTML)

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=...&key=..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start)

[Iframes Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

**Edit:**

Also  [this site](http://embedgooglemaps.com/en/) will generate the link you just need to pick the frame size and location and map type.